# C#-Mysql Insert-Fatal error encountered during command execution

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to execute a INSERT statement on a mySQL DB in C#:

I read my other articles but could not find the right solution!!!!
This fails with the error: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
 **Any ideas on why this would fail?**

```
string sqlQuery;
string sqlQuery2;
int countCat;
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO xs_butiks (siteName,butikCode,butikCategory,butikTitle,butikLink,butikImgLink,butikHtmlCode,butikEndTime,butikStatus) VALUES (@SITE,@CODE,@CATEGORY,@TITLE,@LINK,@IMGLINK,@HTMLCODE,@ENDTIME,@STATUS)";

foreach (DataRow row in butiksTableTrendyol.Rows)
{

    sqlQuery2 = "SELECT * FROM xs_butiks WHERE siteName='Trendyol' AND butikCode='" + row["butikCode"] + "'";
    lock (dblock)
    {
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery2, con))
        {
            countCat = Convert.ToInt32(cmd2.ExecuteScalar());
            if (countCat <= 0)
            {
                lock (dblock)
                {
                    //open connection
                    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) con.Open();
                    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SITE", "Trendyol");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CODE", row["butikCode"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CATEGORY", row["butikCategory"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TITLE", row["butikTitle"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LINK", row["butikLink"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IMGLINK", row["butikImgLink"]);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HTMLCODE", string.Empty);
                        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(row["butikEndTime"].ToString());
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENDTIME", date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STATUS", "pending");
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        var ID = cmd.LastInsertedId;//get inserted ID
                        row["butikID"] = ID;//update dataTable 
                    }
                    //close connection
                    if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed) con.Close();
                }    
            }
        }
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Closed) con.Close();
    }




    /********************************************************************/

    while (isLockedTrendyolButik) ;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        GetTrendyolProducts(row, doc);
    }
    );
    Interlocked.Increment(ref butikCounterTrendyol);//afzayesh yek vahedie globalCounter bad az har request movazi
    if (butikCounterTrendyol == 10) isLockedTrendyolButik = true; //age globalCounter be 10 resid dg request ersal nemishe ta in 10ta tamom beshe. adade 10 ro mitonid be meghdare delkhah bar asase ghodrate server taghir dad. ta zamani ke timeOut ijad nashe in adad ghabele afzayeshe.
}
```

Comment: Any nested exceptions thrown?

Comment: @Darek I am a newcomer. Please note the correct way of problems.

Comment: @Darek This code works properly in localhost. But this error is displayed in Windows Server.

Comment: What line throws the error? What query is it executing?

Comment: @JoelC I think the error is related to incomplete HTML tags html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very possible its a bad datetime.

try this:

```
DateTime date;
bool goodDate = DateTime.TryParse(row["butikEndTime"].ToString(), out date);
if (goodDate)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENDTIME", date);
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENDTIME", DateTime.MinValue);
```